# RShiny: Input multiple image files and put them into a table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to work on a project in shiny to compare images uploaded by user and that saved in my amazon s3 server.

while downloading from s3, I am using this:

```
save_object(object=xyz ,bucket = "xyz", file = paste0("www/",xyz,".jpg"))
```

I'm taking input as:

```
fileInput("image","upload the image")
```

My dataframe is like this:

```
a$name<- xyz

a$server_image<- paste0("<img src=",'"',"xyz.jpg",'"'," ","height=",'"',"300",'"',"></img>")

a$uploaded_image<- paste0("<img src=",'"',input$image$datapath,'"'," ","height=",'"',"300",'"',"></img>")
```

I'm trying to get output like below.

```
output$output_table<-DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(a,escape = FALSE)})
```

In this case, the image downloaded from aws s3 into "www/" directory is correctly showed in the table, but there is problem with viewing uploaded image.

I also tried to use file.copy on input$image to copy it to a folder "www", but it also doesn't work when I deploy the app.

How can I view an image taken using fileInput and View without using renderImage?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that your app renders `<img src=...` before the file is copied in `www`.

A solution is to convert the image in its base64 encoding and then to render the table including the image from its base64 string.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fileInput("image", "upload image"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  base64 <- eventReactive(input$image, {
    base64enc::dataURI(file=input$image$datapath, mime=input$image$type)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$image)
    dat <- data.frame(image = sprintf('<img src=%s height="300"></img>', base64()))
    datatable(dat, escape=FALSE)
  })

})
```